# How do I know if the process is ran manually or by windows start up?

Tags: winapi

I have an application (.exe) written in C++ using QT. After a computer reboot, the application can run as:

1. double click manually on executable
2. from windows startup folder
3. from registry runonce key

Is there any way to know which method was used to run the application. I would like to log this information for some purpose.

Comment: Not with any standard c++ features.

Comment: winapi would do as well

Comment: I think the easiest way is to introduce a command-line flag `--from_startup` and set it in the shortcut that is placed in the startup folder. When the user runs the program manually, that flag won't be passed, so the program will be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Adding a command-line parameter is the only way to detect running from the Registry, but it is not the only way to detect running from a shortcut link.  Another way is for the app to call `GetStartupInfo()` and check the returned `STARTUPINFO` for the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag: "*The `lpTitle` member contains the path of the shortcut file (.lnk) that the user invoked to start this process. This is typically set by the shell when a .lnk file pointing to the launched application is invoked.*" This way, no special command-line parameter needs to be added to the link target.